# Django - Installation django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm a noob with python and Django and I trying to use django-tables2, but my project can't find django-tables2 when I want to make an import.

My Python path is `c:/Python27` and I'm trying to install django-tables2 with (Windows XP, 2.7.3 & Django 1.4):

```
pip install django-tables2
```

Which creates this folder `\Lib\site-packages\django_tables2-0.11.0-py2.7.egg-info` with only these files

```
 27/07/2012  16:45 1      dependency_links.txt
 27/07/2012  16:45 1.422  installed-files.txt
 27/07/2012  16:45 662    PKG-INFO
 27/07/2012  16:45 12     requires.txt
 27/07/2012  16:45 1.271  SOURCES.txt
 27/07/2012  16:45 15     top_level.txt
```

But in the installed-files.txt there are more files that haven't been created.

In my project, an import can't resolve "`import django-tables2`"

Do you know what can be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the command is OK:

```
pip install django-tables2
```

below is the command output:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-tables2
  Downloading django-tables2-0.11.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-tables2

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django-tables2)
Installing collected packages: django-tables2
  Running setup.py install for django-tables2

Successfully installed django-tables2
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [easy_install](http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html) or [setup_tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/)
and install all packs with pip install or etc.

Answer (score -1):

try sudo pip ...
mybe you need root to install that

Comment: this is a windows install, no sudo there.